# Just started a new spree app, but can't find a way to generate theme_default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Anyone know how to generate a default_theme so that it can be edited? It seems that all the core files are hidden and uneditable.

The last working spree app I made started with theme_default exposed under vendor/plugins.

Because this one is in Rails3, I pulled it right from the official railsdog git, thus no theme_default, and no haml.

I'm probably missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to create your own views, the starting point is to create our own extension. You can achieve this with the command you'll find here:

http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/extensions.html#creatingan-extension

Then it's like any raRails Engine, you can create the views you want, they'll override spree's.

Comment: Yah so..finding the files in my /core in /gems/spree I thought I would just copy and paste them over to a generated extension. But it caused a series of really bad fails when trying to either boot the server up or run a migration. If i create the extension by itself, it comes empty. I am looking to have every working file it runs currently at my perusal inside the master tree.. which i still believe can be done by first creating the extension and in some clever way, copying over the files from the core, i just don't know how.

Comment: Another way to do is to use hooks as described here: http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/01/rails-ecommerce-spree-hooks-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Is `rake sandbox` what you are looking for? See [Building a Sandbox Application](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/source_code.html#buildinga-sandbox-application)

Comment: i'm guessing that's placing all the core files into the application.. but.. its also placing it in my /.gitignore so am I to assume they are just for messing around and not for any real purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You only do `rake sandbox` just for test purpose, I have found this [link](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/customization_tutorial.html)

Change the command for `rails g spree:extension [ext_name]`.